# Xamarin Android WebView - storing local content outside assets possible?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview

I am using xamarin forms and for android I would like to fetch local web content (not store it in android assets) so that it can be updated independently of the app itself.

What folder should be used as I know that WebView is running as separate process so not all folders are accessible?
Is there any doc describing what folders WebView can reach?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to add the html in raw folder for the Resource folder. Android provideds `Resources.OpenRawResource` to read the stream from the file.

Create a raw folder inside the Resource folder. And add the local html file in it.

The code sample below for your reference:

```
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout4);

        var stream = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.local);//local is the html file.(local.html)

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        var text = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            text.AppendLine(line);
        }


        var webView1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);

        webView1.LoadData(text.ToString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```